# Lambda function c# meaning

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have some code which is failing - actually I cannot edit it. Following here and I'm trying to figure out the operation of this code, i.e. what this is doing. Its failing, but I do not know where exactly.

```
Dictionary<long, IList<Cell>> ByBlock =
                mCache.ListBlocks.SelectMany(e => e.Value).Where(e => listBlocks.Contains(e.Key)).Select(
                Block => new KeyValuePair<long, IList<CellToSubCatchment>>(Block.Key,
                    DataMgr.GetMapping(
                    "CASH",
                    Block,
                    GetKey(IdKeys, Block),
                    mType))).ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value);
```

I'm getting the error: `Value cannot be null`, but I do not know what value is null and since I cannot edit the code or run Lambda's in the immediate window, I'm having trouble debugging this. So any ideas on how it works or the better way to look at these lambdas?

Comment: Welcome to the pain of lambdas (I actually like them but handling errors is a pain). I'd suggest splitting it down into several one liners, re-running and working out which statement is causing the problem.

Comment: @Liath I totally second that - I also like lambda expressions, but unfortunately no new lambda expressions can be formulated while debugging!

Comment: @Codor good point. To clarify I mean var a =  mCache.ListBlocks.SelectMany(); var b = a.Where(); var c = b.Select() and so on... it's horrible but you'll need to modify your code to find the culprit

Comment: I believe that at some point, the generated `Value` would be `null`, such that the conversion to a dictionary fails; perhaps the `SelectMany` fails.

Comment: you can watch bpth mCache and listblocks in the watch window is neither is null then e is (an item in the collection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit misleading since dictionaries have keys and values, but you'll get that error when trying to insert a `null` key into a `Dictionary` (you're allowed to have `null` values in a dictionary).

I think you can filter out `null` values earlier on in your query so you don't end up with a `null` key later on. I added a condition for `&& e.Key != null`.

```
Dictionary<long, IList<Cell>> ByBlock =
    mCache.ListBlocks.SelectMany(e => e.Value)
          .Where(e => listBlocks.Contains(e.Key)
                      && e.Key != null)  // filter out `null` values
          .Select(Block =>
                    new KeyValuePair<long, IList<CellToSubCatchment>>(
                        Block.Key,
                        DataMgr.GetMapping("CASH", Block,
                                           GetKey(IdKeys, Block),
                                           mType)))
          .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Reformating the code a bit it looks like this:

```
Dictionary<long, IList<Cell>> ByBlock = 
       mCache.ListBlocks
         .SelectMany(e => e.Value)
         .Where(e => listBlocks.Contains(e.Key))
         .Select(Block => new KeyValuePair<long, IList<CellToSubCatchment>>(
                Block.Key,
                DataMgr.GetMapping("CASH",Block,GetKey(IdKeys, Block), mType))
         )
         .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value);
```

My best bet would be that the `ListBlocks.SelectMany(e => e.Value)` call fails, because in the `ListBlocks` collection there is a element that has a `Value` collection equal to null.

This is a quirk of `SelectMany`, and I usually go around it using something like

```
mCache.ListBlocks.SelectMany(e => e.Value ?? List<MyType>())
```

---

EDIT:
On closer view, that case just throws a `NullReferenceException`, the `ArgumentNullException` you are recieving is more likely to come from the `ToDictionary` call.

Also, you could remove the second `Select` call, as well as the painful-to-look-at `KeyValuePair` constructior, by just using the `ToDictionary` method to do the evaluation:

```
Dictionary<long, IList<Cell>> ByBlock = 
       mCache.ListBlocks
         .SelectMany(e => e.Value)
         .Where(e => listBlocks.Contains(e.Key))
         .ToDictionary(
              block => block.Key, 
              block => DataMgr.GetMapping("CASH",block,GetKey(IdKeys, block), mType))
         );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I like to do with messy LINQ. It makes it much easier to read and debug.

```
var allListBlockValues = mCache.ListBlocks.SelectMany(listBlock => listBlock.Value);

var matchingListBlockValues = allListBlockValues.Where(e => listBlocks.Contains(e.Key))


Dictionary<long, IList<Cell>> ByBlock = new Dictionary<long, IList<Cell>>();

foreach (var Block in matchingListBlockValues)
{
     long key = Block.Key;
     var value = DataMgr.GetMapping("CASH",Block,GetKey(IdKeys, Block), mType);

     ByBlock.Add(key, value);
}
```